# Best practice to swap a string for another & swap back

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings in a database which cannot be changed.

I need to swap them with user readable strings and also be able to swap from the user readable back to the database string.

So, 
"acura" = "Acura",
"nissan" = "Nissan",
"landrover" = "Land Rover"

I can think of some array and list based ways to do this, but I'm thinking there might be an easier method. 
What is the easiest solution to do this ? Thanks

Comment: It would be hard to tell if a string like landrover was actually two words...

Comment: Modify them on the fly.. Swap them back is as simple as read the database again

Comment: Is there an way to do this with an enum ?

Comment: dictionary is the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's no direct correlation (e.g. you can't just Capitalize the first letter) you can use Generic `Dictionary<string, string>` with key being DB string and Value - user visible string.

This way strings will always be in sync and easy to locate.

```
myList.Add("acura", "Acura"); // myList["acura"] == "Acura"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a simple table with two columns: internal_name and display_name. Join with that table when you want to show user friendly names for things.

I thing the mappings belongs in the database with the data being mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
List<Tuple<string,string>> data = new ...
//Populate the data here
foreach(Tuple t in data)
{
    t.Item1="acura";  //Read and write 
    t.Item2="Acura";  //Read and write 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Yuriy's answer if you only wanted it in a single language/culture, i.e. English/US. I mention culture as well as language because car names and brands vary by country, even in those who speak English.

If you need it localized, then a resource based approach is warranted, where the database value is used as the resource string name, and the friendly name the resource string value.

If the list is static then you could use resx files for the appropriate cultures, which is the easiest to implement, or if it's dynamic use your database.